# Change Custom Post Type ID on Gravity Forms Email

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using the function/filter below to get a list of Properties (houses, flats etc) from the WP Property Hive plugin, and then using this list to populate a dropdown (select) on a Gravity Forms form.

Currently the code works as expected, populating the dropdown with the correct properties and their respective names.

```
function get_property_names() {
  $property_names = array();
  // Retrieve the list of properties from WP Property Hive
  $properties = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'property',  // Post type property
    'posts_per_page' => -1,          // Retrieve all properties
    'meta_query'     => array(
      array(
        'key'   => '_department',  // Search Department
        'value' => 'residential-lettings',   // Residential Lettings
      )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'availability',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('to-let'),
      )
    ),
  ));
  // Loop through the properties and extract the names
  foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $property_names[$property->ID] = $property->post_title;
  }
  return $property_names;
}

add_filter('gform_pre_render', 'populate_property_names');
function populate_property_names($form) {
  foreach ($form['fields'] as &$field) {
    if ($field->type == 'select' && $field->inputName == 'ja_tolet') {
      $property_names = get_property_names();
      // Convert property names array to choices for the dropdown field
      $choices = array();
      foreach ($property_names as $property_id => $property_name) {
        $choices[] = array(
          'text'  => $property_name,
          'value' => $property_id,
        );
      }
      // Modify the field choices
      $field->choices = $choices;
    }
  }
  return $form;
}
```

My issue is that on the notification email the form sends out, instead of adding the property name, it is adding the property ID. I had a go at adding something like below to my code to alter the Property ID to Name on the email but it doesnt work.

UPDATED: The code below now changes the Property ID on the wordpress wp-admin Gravity Forms Entries, which lists form entries, to the Property Name. But still doesnt change it on the email that is sent out.

```
add_filter('gform_notification', 'replace_property_id_with_name', 10, 3);
function replace_property_id_with_name($notification, $form, $entry) {
  $property_names = get_property_names();

  foreach ($notification['fields'] as &$field) {
    if ($field['type'] === 'select' && $field['inputName'] === 'ja_tolet') {
      $property_id = $entry[$field['id']];
      $property_name = isset($property_names[$property_id]) ? $property_names[$property_id] : '';

      $field['content'] = str_replace("{Property ID:{$property_id}}", $property_name, $field['content']);
      $field['content'] = str_replace("{Property ID: {$property_id}}", $property_name, $field['content']);
    }
  }

  return $notification;
}

add_filter('gform_entry_field_value', 'replace_property_id_with_name_entry', 10, 4);
function replace_property_id_with_name_entry($value, $field, $entry, $form) {
  if ($field->inputName === 'ja_tolet') {
    $property_names = get_property_names();
    $property_id = $entry[$field->id];
    $property_name = isset($property_names[$property_id]) ? $property_names[$property_id] : '';
    $value = $property_name;
  }
  return $value;
}
```

Is there an error in my code causing the Property ID to be on the email instead of the Name, or can anyone help me alter the email so that the correct information (Property Name) appears?

Thanks

Comment: `$choices[] = array( 'text' => $property_name, 'value' => $property_id, );` - just set `value` to the property _name_ in there ...?